# Errors in Siddhi app.Different definition same as output 'define stream

Tags: wso2, wso2-enterprise-integrator, wso2-streaming-integrator

I create a stream to read data from csv and write it in Postgresql it do everything just insert data on db:
my csv consist of 1,test,1
my stream :

```
@App:name("StockFile")

@App:description('test ...')

@source(type='file',
dir.uri='file:C:\file',
action.after.process='NONE',
@map(type='csv'))
define stream IntputStream (Amount int, Location string,  ProductId int);

@store(type = 'rdbms',
jdbc.url = "jdbc:postgresql://localhost:5432/postgres",
username = "xxx",
password = "xxx",
jdbc.driver.name = "org.postgresql.Driver",
table.name = 'Test',
operation = 'insert', 
@map(type = 'keyvalue' ))
define stream outputstream (Amount int, Location string,  ProductId int);

@info(name = 'Save stock records')
from IntputStream 
select Amount,Location,ProductId
insert into outputstream;
```

Answer (score 0):

When you define a table, the definition should be a table definition so the correct way to define the `outputstream` is

```
@store(type = 'rdbms',jdbc.url = "jdbc:postgresql://localhost:5432/postgres",username = "xxx",password = "xxx",jdbc.driver.name = "org.postgresql.Driver",table.name = 'Test',operation = 'insert', @map(type = 'keyvalue' ))
define table outputstream (Amount int, Location string,  ProductId int);
```